# Angular Virtual Scrolling and Browseranimation Renderbug

Tags: angular

I can't use browser animations and cdkVirtualScrolling without renderBugs.

See the following example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nutyca?file=src/app/app.module.ts

After click the "toggle list" button, you can see the render bug in list 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the height of the container changes when toggleing between the 2 viewports.

Either create a div around them with fixed heights or you have to triggera re-check after the animation finishes.

A quick and dirty proof of concept: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4yx36?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanks, for the quick answer! I think this is the best solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xsgymq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: yea thats pretty clean - no more dirty timeouts ;)